# AngularJS redirect not occurring in interceptor

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angular-http-interceptors

I'm using a very simple interceptor to check responseRejection for 403 Access Forbidden to redirect users to the login, but it doesn't redirect.  I can console.log right up to the line before $location.path and after it, and it never occurs.  Has anyone else had this happen?  I've been staring at this for a bit now...  Originally I didn't even want to use $location, but I can't inject ui.router without getting a circular dependency, which I also can't figure out how to get rid of so $location was supposed to keep me moving, while I thought about it.

```
.factory('AuthInterceptor', ['$q', '$location',
    function( $q, $location ) {

    var service = {
        responseError: function( responseRejection ) {

            // Authorization issue, access forbidden
            if( responseRejection.status === 403 ) {

                // TODO: show a login dialog, and/or redirect to login
                console.log("Response rejected. Redirecting to login...");

                $location.path('/login');
                $location.replace();

                console.log("Not so much with the redirecting... I'm still here");
            }

            // Propagate error to any chained promise handlers
            return $q.reject( responseRejection );
        }
    }

    return service;
}])
```

Comment: When you do `$location.path` the statement next to it will run because the path change will occur only in the next digest cycle. You cannot probably directly inject `$state` instead you can inject `$injector` and get `$injector.get('$state').go(statename)`. Also setting location path or href etc are not blocking activity, meaning it will let the current script to execute completely and then change the locaiton.

Comment: Thanks, injecting $injector works, and I didn't know about non-blocking activity so thank you again :)  You should drop this into an answer below so it's more visible, and you get more credit. Thanks again

Comment: Glad it works. Sure, I will drop an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting the window location using `location.href` it does set the location immediately and stop the execution of scripts, but the location change will be effective only when the current script path under execution is completed. That is why you see statement below href gets executed. It is not a blocking activity as well (unlike alert or prompt). When setting location using the angular wrapper it will take effect after the digest cycle. And you have a valid issue of circular dependency  when injecting `$state` in `$http` interceptor. To overcome that you can get the instance of `$state` by using `$injector.`

```
.factory('AuthInterceptor', ['$q', '$injector',
    function( $q, $injector ) {

    var $state;

    var service = {
        responseError: function( responseRejection ) {

            // Authorization issue, access forbidden
            if( responseRejection.status === 403 ) {

                // TODO: show a login dialog, and/or redirect to login
                console.log("Response rejected. Redirecting to login...");

                _setState('login');

                console.log("Not so much with the redirecting... I'm still here");
            }

            // Propagate error to any chained promise handlers
            return $q.reject( responseRejection );
        }
    }
   function _setState(stateName){
        if(!$state) {
          $injector.get('$state'); //Or just get $state from $injector always it is anyways the dependency container and service are singletons
        }
       $state.go(stateName);
    }
    return service;
}]);
```

Comment: I already follow same like your code but routing not working properly. In url into successfully route but view can't displaying . Can you just guide me.